# What does «наяву» mean?

Tags: значения

Google translate doesn't do a good job of explaining it. Could someone please give common context in which it is used?

Answer (score 9):

This is an adverb meaning "in reality", as opposed to *во сне* ("in one's dream"), *в бреду* ("in one's delirium") etc.

- *Я часто говорю с ним во сне, но никогда наяву* / I often talk to him in my dreams, but never in reality.

Comment: I believe the more important connonation to know is "in **reality**" as opposed to "in a dream". Will definitely make the answer complete.

Answer (score 6):

"Наяву" comes from old russian world "Явь". "Явь" it's some kind of reality, for example like real world (when we speak about heaven, hell and real life).
Nowadays "Явь" evolved to word "наяву" - "in this reality", "in this world", not in dreams or imagination.

Comment: Could you please provide a source for *явь* meaning *a kind of reality* in Old Russian?

Comment: @Quassnoi Well, I thought "явь"means reality in Modern Russian, too. :) Just not in much use except in fiction. Probably, *dmaltsev* meant that the Russian word "явь" is old, which is true: there indeed was «ѩвѣ» in Old Russian. Check Wiktionary, it usually has info on etymolody from Vasmer's dictionary.

Comment: @Shady_arc: there's little doubt about the meaning in Modern Russian. There's also none about the existence of the word you mentioned in Old Russian (though it's not even a noun but adverb meaning "openly", "clearly"). My doubt is that the word *явь* (with the modern meaning) existed in Old Russian and is not a recent innovation. But I can easily be disproved with a but single reference.

Comment: This question is more correct one as it is based on the existence of [явь](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%8F%D0%B2%D1%8C). Following the link you can see synonyms (синонимы) and antonyms (антонимы) to help you understand meaning easier based on more often used words: reality, partially not a dream, etc. As well as origin.

Answer (score 0):

Наяву - этот состояние, когда ты не спишь (бодрствуешь), не бредишь, когда ты находишься "в здравом уме и твердой памяти", когда окружающая действительность реальная, и не является плодом вашего воображения.

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ.  Однако он не содержит никакой дополнительной информации по отношению к другим ответам.

Comment: @AleksG А почему должен? Каждый предлагает свой ответ. А автор вопроса выбирает тот, который, по его мнению в наибольшей степени разрешает его вопрос. Разве не так?